# Problems with SQL Server 2014 CTP 1 installation

Tags: sql-server-2014

I tried to install 2014 version a week ago but ended up with some conflicts. Today I tried to install 2012 instead, but when I ran installation, bootstrap did extract 2012 files but then , for some reason, 2014 installation was started. Is there any way to clear the cache or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap`. It said SQl server 2012 but it was actually 2014 and installation worked this time